# Rails terminal clogged with loading bootstrap files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, terminal

I am using Rails 4 and the bootstrap 2 gem (haven't figure out is there is an official / well supported bootstrap 3 gem yet) for my web app.

But the problem is as I'm trying to work through the server logs in my terminal, it is clogged up with a bunch of bootstrap get requests:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/messages.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/styles.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:48:59 -0800


Started GET "/assets/task_sessions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:49:00 -0800


Started GET "/assets/tasks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:49:00 -0800


Started GET "/assets/welcome.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 13:49:00 -0800
```

Is there any way to not make those things appear for every single request to make debugging and going through the log easier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a gem called `quiet_assets` which does pretty much what you want.

https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets

Simply add `gem 'quiet_assets', group: :development` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

By default it suppresses your assets log messages but you can optionally switch it back on.